# Question on resolvent set in linear equations

Tags: functional-analysis

$I$ is the identity operator on a Banach space $E$. $U$ is a bounded linear operator mapping E into itself. Then $I-hU$ is a operator and suppose $h$ belongs to the resolvent set of $U$. Given the equation
\begin{equation}
x-hU(x)=y 
\end{equation}
if $|h|<1/||U||$,the solutions could be written in the form
\begin{equation}
x=y+\sum_{i=1}^\infty h^nU^n(y) \\
U^1=U,U^n=U(U^{n-1})
\end{equation}
Why is the solution like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r = |h| \|U\|$, then $\|h^n U^n y\| \le |h|^n \|U\|^n \|y\| = r^n \|y\|$ so the series converges.  Now just plug $x = y + \sum_{i=1}^\infty h^n U^n y$ in to the equation to see that it is satisfied.

Moreover, if there was another solution $\tilde{x}$, we'd have $\|x - \tilde{x}\| =  \|h U x - h U \tilde{x}\| \le r \|x -\tilde{x}\|$, which is impossible if $\|x - \tilde{x}\| > 0$.